# Message about already having edited 15 posts by retagging them

Tags: support, tags, rate-limiting

I got this message right now:

[image: screenshot]

The edits it refers to were only retaggings, as far as I can tell. However, *I can still retag my posts*.

- Does retagging count towards the "At most 15 edits to old posts" limits?
- Why can I still retag?

Comment: After 15 it stops screwing up the front page.  I hope anyway :)

Comment: I'd upvote, but it's currently on +15.